# Change value of a particular row in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I’ve the following data

```
|Col1 | Col2|
|:———-|———-:|
|X    | 100 |
|Y    | 2   |
|Z    | 500 |
```

I want to change the value of Y to 150 for this code i’m using is:

```
x=150
df = df.loc[df.Col1 == ‘Y’, ‘Col2’]=x
```

But this shows an error numpy.float64 object has no attribute ‘loc’

Comment: You don't have a pandas dataframe, you have a numpy array.

Comment: does "value of Y" means the position of the Y itself, or the corresponding value in the other column, here "2" ?

Comment: You're assigning `x` to `df`. Try with `df.loc[df.Col1 == ‘Y’, ‘Col2’]=x`

Comment: @azro the value 2 in other column